# Keep style for substituted text

Tags: javascript, jquery, substitution

pls help me in solving the following issue:

I have to substitute h1 on page with another keyword through Google Tag Manager. Question How can I keep the style of original text for the new one:

I use the following code:

```
<script>
  if ({{URL -utm_term}}=='elgin') {jQuery('#main > div > div > div > section.elementor-section.elementor-top-section.elementor-element.elementor-element-5373a06.elementor-hidden-tablet.elementor-hidden-phone.elementor-section-boxed.elementor-section-height-default.elementor-section-height-default > div > div > div > div > div > div.elementor-element.elementor-element-9afed50.elementor-widget__width-initial.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-heading > div > h1').replaceWith('Attic Insulation Elgin');
} else if ({{URL -utm_term}}=='evanston') {jQuery('#main > div > div > div > section.elementor-section.elementor-top-section.elementor-element.elementor-element-5373a06.elementor-hidden-tablet.elementor-hidden-phone.elementor-section-boxed.elementor-section-height-default.elementor-section-height-default > div > div > div > div > div > div.elementor-element.elementor-element-9afed50.elementor-widget__width-initial.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-heading > div > h1').replaceWith('Attic Insulation Evanston');
} else {
  {{URL -utm_term}} = "#main > div > div > div > section.elementor-section.elementor-top-section.elementor-element.elementor-element-5373a06.elementor-hidden-tablet.elementor-hidden-phone.elementor-section-boxed.elementor-section-height-default.elementor-section-height-default > div > div > div > div > div > div.elementor-element.elementor-element-9afed50.elementor-widget__width-initial.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-heading > div > h1";
}
</script>
```

Thank You a lot

Answer (score 1):

Replace the data of the text node instead of the h1 itself

```html
<script>
  if ({{URL -utm_term}}=='elgin') {jQuery('#main > div > div > div > section.elementor-section.elementor-top-section.elementor-element.elementor-element-5373a06.elementor-hidden-tablet.elementor-hidden-phone.elementor-section-boxed.elementor-section-height-default.elementor-section-height-default > div > div > div > div > div > div.elementor-element.elementor-element-9afed50.elementor-widget__width-initial.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-heading > div > h1').text('Attic Insulation Elgin');
} else if ({{URL -utm_term}}=='evanston') {jQuery('#main > div > div > div > section.elementor-section.elementor-top-section.elementor-element.elementor-element-5373a06.elementor-hidden-tablet.elementor-hidden-phone.elementor-section-boxed.elementor-section-height-default.elementor-section-height-default > div > div > div > div > div > div.elementor-element.elementor-element-9afed50.elementor-widget__width-initial.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-heading > div > h1').text('Attic Insulation Evanston');
} else {
  {{URL -utm_term}} = "#main > div > div > div > section.elementor-section.elementor-top-section.elementor-element.elementor-element-5373a06.elementor-hidden-tablet.elementor-hidden-phone.elementor-section-boxed.elementor-section-height-default.elementor-section-height-default > div > div > div > div > div > div.elementor-element.elementor-element-9afed50.elementor-widget__width-initial.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-heading > div > h1";
}
</script>
```